# What is the EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports target?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

In some of my csproj files I have this but some dont:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

What exactly is this and why do I need it?  My other projects are restoring their packages just fine **without it**.

I am using VS2013 and NuGet 2.8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It ensures that the imported .props and .targets files are indeed imported. NuGet has supported NuGet MSBuild support since [2.5](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5). EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports code was added in September, but I think it is a 2.8 change. Unfortunately, it looks like a non-backward compatible change. We have some developers on 2.7 who will now need to upgrade to 2.8. I found EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports in Common/[MsBuildProjectUtility.cs](https://github.com/ctaggart/nuget/commits/master/Common/MsBuildProjectUtility.cs) on [line 11](https://github.com/ctaggart/nuget/blob/b0dbfe7e8aeecec1c7f41ca8e48b147a97c97172/Common/MsBuildProjectUtility.cs#L11).

Comment: I wonder if "ctaggart/nuget" repository (the one you linked) is really accurate. Maybe you link to "NuGet/NuGet.Client" instead. It also has the [MSBuildProjectSystem.cs file](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/fee9da08b687e9d18073243d46f6d46ad660dd4c/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Common/MSBuildProjectSystem.cs) with that EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports and it seem to be the official nuget source.

Comment: It seems that `EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports` do not care the existence of the nuget package?

Comment: What does "NuGet has supported NuGet MSBuild support" mean?

Comment: What causes it to get added to the csproj? It just showed up in mine in a commit and I don't know what I did that added it. It's referencing Microsoft.Web.WEbJobs.Publish.2.0.0 so I'm guessing publishing from VS did it, but I'm pretty sure that wasn't the first time anyone has done that.